# android-Why my seekbar looks bad

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I'm using appcompact theme, When I use seek bar I get this :

[image]

I want to have something like this :

[image]

or any other color I want ,How can I do so  ?

thanks

Comment: [Styling seekbar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16165498/1777090), and [for appcompat theme](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18217520/1777090)

Comment: You are seeing your seekbar the way you do because of the theme. If you don't override anything, on different android versions the seekbar will be displayed accordingly.

Comment: you need to show custom seek bar or use Appcompact theme